# How to create table in doc using poi

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, hwpf

I try to create table in `.doc` file. I didn't getting much help to create table in `doc` using poi. I try below code but it didn't work. It's didn't create table like below screenshot.

[image]

```
private static void insertTable() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("/home/ikadmin/Downloads/in.doc"));
        int rows = 3, columns = 3;
        Range range = doc.getRange();
        Table table = range.insertTableBefore((short) columns, rows);
        for (int rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < table.numRows(); rowIdx++) {
            TableRow row = table.getRow(rowIdx);
            for (int colIdx = 0; colIdx < row.numCells(); colIdx++) {
                TableCell cell = row.getCell(colIdx);

                Paragraph par = cell.getParagraph(0);

                par.insertBefore("" + (rowIdx * row.numCells() + colIdx));
            }
        }
        String newFilePath = "/home/ikadmin/Downloads/out.doc";
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newFilePath);
        doc.write(out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
```

currently I use POI 3.11 version.

Your help will be highly appreciated

Comment: for your kind information @DirkVollmar it's code for `.docx` not `.doc` . Please remove it's not duplicate question.

Comment: Reopened. Though it is still a possible duplicate: [HWPF-POI: Inserting table in Word with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28341881/hwpf-poi-inserting-table-in-word-with-java)

Comment: it's not working I already try that same result .

Comment: Yes, Already try with Microsoft Word same result @AxelRichter